# how to add text watermark under the original content using itext7.1

Tags: java, itext7

i have 2 problems which i am not able to solve.
1- I want to have transparent watermark or i should say it should be behind the original text. currently it is hiding the original text.
2- i want to make more dark color watermark. its coming very much light gray color.

when i dont know what is the page size.This code will be helpful for different size of pages. A1, A2, A3, A4 all different size of pages you can use and watermark will come in the middle. I am getting the watermark but having two problems.

```
 public static void watermarkPDF(PdfDocument pdfDoc, String watermarkText) 
    throws IOException
    {

    float formXOffset = 0;
    float formYOffset = 0;
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont();

    int numberOfPages = pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages();
    PdfPage page = null;


    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
    {
        page = pdfDoc.getPage(i);
        Rectangle ps = page.getPageSize();
        float width = ps.getWidth();
        float height = ps.getHeight();
        float fontSize = Math.min(width, height) / 12;
        height = height / 2;
        width = width / 2;
        //Center the annotation     
        Rectangle watermarkTrimmingRectangle = new Rectangle(ps.getWidth(), ps.getHeight() );
        PdfWatermarkAnnotation watermark = new PdfWatermarkAnnotation(watermarkTrimmingRectangle);

        //Apply linear algebra rotation math
        //Create identity matrix
        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();//No-args constructor creates the identity transform

        float textwidth = font.getWidth(watermarkText, fontSize);

        float remainarea = ps.getWidth()-textwidth;

        //Apply translation
        transform.translate(remainarea/2, height);
        //Apply rotation
        //transform.rotate(45f);

        PdfFixedPrint fixedPrint = new PdfFixedPrint();
        watermark.setFixedPrint(fixedPrint);
        //Create appearance
        Rectangle formRectangle = new Rectangle(formXOffset, formYOffset,  ps.getWidth(), ps.getHeight());

        //Observation: font XObject will be resized to fit inside the watermark rectangle
        PdfFormXObject form = new PdfFormXObject(formRectangle);
        PdfExtGState gs1 = new PdfExtGState().setFillOpacity(0.1f);
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(form, pdfDoc);

        float[] transformValues = new float[6];
        transform.getMatrix(transformValues);
        canvas.saveState()
            .beginText().setFillColorGray((float) 0.1).setExtGState(gs1)
            .setTextMatrix(transformValues[0], transformValues[1], transformValues[2], transformValues[3], transformValues[4], transformValues[5])
            .setFontAndSize(font, fontSize)
            .showText(watermarkText)
            .endText()
            .restoreState();

        canvas.release();

        watermark.setAppearance(PdfName.N, new PdfAnnotationAppearance(form.getPdfObject()));
        watermark.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);

        page.addAnnotation(watermark);

    }
    page.flush();
    pdfDoc.close();
}
```

Watermark should not hide the original content of the file. and it should be dark enough when I take printout it should be visible.

Comment: Alternatively mostly transparant watermark _over_ the page. This prevents any problems with filled (white) background.

Comment: Your code creates a mostly transparent (Opacity 0.1) watermark over the page. Have you tried with other opacity values? Alternatively have you tried using a different rendering mode (e.g. **Darken** or **Multiply**) instead of transparency?

Comment: Thanks for your comments Joop and mkl. yes I am getting the transparent watermark with the given opacity. but when i take print this watermark doesn't visible in Page. so i think i need to darken the watermark but also has to make it transparent. i dont know how to use rendering can you please help me.

Comment: I am managed to find the watermark. It is available somewhere in the page. If i change the page size and landscape/portrait view watermark will  come but its not in the middle. How can i fix this watermark to middle while printing? If i use the paragraph i can get it but i am using rectangle and form for annotation and on top of that i can add my watermark paragraph. because at some point i need to remove as well. Any other way to remove the watermark apart from annotation? Because this annotation is creating problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static void removeWatermarkFromPDF(PdfDocument pdfDocument) throws IOException {
    PdfObject obj;
    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        PdfArray contentObjects = pdfDocument.getPage(i).getPdfObject().getAsArray(PdfName.Contents);
        for (int j = 0; j <= contentObjects.size() - 1; j++) {
            obj = contentObjects.get(j);
            if (obj != null && obj.isStream()) {
                byte[] b;
                try {
                    b = ((PdfStream) obj).getBytes();
                } catch (PdfException exc) {
                    b = ((PdfStream) obj).getBytes(false);
                }
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                baos.write(b);
                if (baos.toString().contains("iText Watermark")) {
                    contentObjects.remove(j);
                }
                baos.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST));
        addWatermark(pdfDocument, "iText Watermark");
        pdfDocument.close();

        pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(DEST), new PdfWriter(DEST2));
        removeWatermarkFromPDF(pdfDocument);
        pdfDocument.close();
}
```

```
public static void addWatermark(PdfDocument pdfDocument, String text) throws Exception {
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont();

        PdfExtGState gs1 = new PdfExtGState();
        gs1.setFillOpacity(0.2f);

        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(i);
            float fontSize = Math.min(page.getPageSize().getWidth(), page.getPageSize().getHeight()) / 12;
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph(text)
                    .setFontColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY, 0.2f).setFont(font).setFontSize(fontSize);
            PdfCanvas under = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamBefore(), new PdfResources(), pdfDocument);
            under.setExtGState(gs1);
            new Canvas(under, pdfDocument, pdfDocument.getDefaultPageSize())
                    .showTextAligned(p,
                            page.getPageSize().getWidth() / 2,
                            page.getPageSize().getHeight() / 2,
                            1, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
        }

        pdfDocument.close();
}
```

Comment: I have added the answer from Itext support. but i don't know why it doesn't show properly as a code block. May be stack overflow admin can correct.